# Loading PokéAPI Image data

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, axios

So basically I want to show images from the PokéAPI on my homescreen whenever somebody opens the app but for showing 30 images, I have to call 30 different APIs as well.
I can't call the apis after every few seconds also because I think its a bad approach,

For example, the Pokémon API for getting Pokémon data:

> https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/?limit=20&offset=30

The response from the API looks like:

```json
{
  // ...
  "results": [
    {
       "name": "nidoqueen",
       "url": "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/31/"
    },
    {
       "name": "nidoran-m",
       "url": "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/32/"
    },
    // ...
  ]
}
```

Now I have to use these URLs and then call the Axios/fetch and then show images, is there any better way to do it or that's the only way?

Comment: Unless the API documentation indicates another way to get the data you're looking for, making requests to those URLs would likely indeed be how you get that information.

Comment: I think that the PokéAPI is a [HATEOAS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HATEOAS) API.

Comment: You are supposed to [cache the retrieved data](https://pokeapi.co/docs/v2#fairuse), not make API calls to it every time, otherwise you risk a ban.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to get the default sprite for a Pokémon you will have to fetch that Pokémon by name or ID.

Once you have the data, you can get the default sprite.

```html
<div id="root"></div>
<script type="text/babel" data-presets="es2017,react">
/* BEGIN ES2017 (ES8) React code... */
const { useEffect, useState } = React;

const fetchPokemonInfo = async (name) => {
  const res = await fetch(`https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/${name}`, {
    cache: 'force-cache',
  });
  return await res.json();
};

const PokemonSprite = ({ name }) => {
  const [data, setData] = useState({});

  useEffect(() => {
    (async () => {
      const info = await fetchPokemonInfo(name.toLowerCase());
      setData(info);
    })();
  }, [name]);

  return <img src={data?.sprites?.front_default} alt={name} />;
};

const favoritePokemon = ["Charizard", "Scyther", "Mew"];

const App = () => {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      {favoritePokemon.map((name) => (
        <PokemonSprite key={name} name={name} />
      ))}
    </div>
  );
};

ReactDOM
  .createRoot(document.getElementById('root'))
  .render(<App />);
/* END ES2017 (ES8) React code... */
</script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-standalone/7.23.1/babel.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/18.2.0/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/18.2.0/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
```